# How do I change the owner/group of a file in my server?

Tags: group-policy, ownership

I am getting a 500 error because the owner of some of my files is set incorrectly, its set at 0 0 when the rest are at 510 510?? How do I fix this, I've read something about ssh?

Comment: This question probably would do better on SuperUser/ServerFault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, SSH is right. You need to use SSH to connect to your server (using openssh and the "ssh" program in Linux, or PuTTy in Windows) and issue the command webdestroya already posted:

```
$ ssh yourserver -l username <host>
OR
$ ssh yourserver [username@]<host>
```

And then issue the command to change your file permissions:

```
$ chown 510:510 thefile.file
```

Comment: Some SCP clients (like winSCP) will also allow to set file permissions - this way you don't have to bother with the console.

Comment: Why "bother"? I love my consoles :)

Answer (score 1):

`chown 510:510 thefile.file`

Answer (score 1):

If it is a linux server, you can use the `chown` and `chgrp` commands to change the owner and group of a file.

You can also use the `chmod` command to change the permissions of a given file - EG: `777` means that everyone has access to a file (probably not what you want, just an example: